# AWS API Gateway Lambda API http request body handling

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, httprequest

What is the best practice to handle request body when API Gateway directed the request to lambda. I'm using node.js

In express app, we have bodyparser, what should I use in lambda?

I tested by putting some variables inside body, and when I console.log the request body, it is a whole string. I can use JSON.parse to transfer it as json. But how about images, files?

Comment: `multipart/form-data` request bodies (which is what you'd use to upload images/files) are not currently supported by the API Gateway => Lambda integration. You could attempt to get around this by base64 encoding all the binary and sending it as JSON, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express